# QML precreate items to show in a StackView

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to instantiate items and then display them using a **StackView**, via

```
MyItem0
{
    id: item0
}

MyItem1
{
    id: item1
}

myStackView.push(item0)
...
myStackView.pop()
myStackView.push(item1)
```

The problem is that when I create items item0 and item1, they are all shown, which is obviously not what I want.

I guess it somehow relates to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227223/stackview-alternative-in-qml).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the items as properties rather than children, which will result in them not showing until they are pushed on the stack view:

```
property Item item0: MyItem0 { }
property Item item1: MyItem1 { }
```

However, if you pop, the item will remain visible, as its parent will no longer be null.

`pop()` is said to return the popped item, so `pop().parent = null` should do the trick, but for me for some reason it returns a `null`.

So instead you can simply set the parent explicitly to null:

```
  pop()
  item0.parent = null
```

Naturally, you can just as well set the `visible` or `opacity` properties. Which may be preferable, as even more funky and illogical behavior surfaces. if you try to push the same item again after it has been pushed and popped once, it doesn't work, and there is an `nothing to push` error message in the debug console.

Edit: OK, regarding the last paragraph, it seems that whatever method used, once an object has been pushed and popped, the same object cannot be pushed again, even if the parent is not set to null. This looks like a bug.

Comment: I observe the same behavior, this is a pain.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why I stay away from using stock controls. They work very well when you only limit yourself to "by the book" usage, but the moment you try to do something more free-style and they epically fail. I am like "I am going to build my own stack view, with blackjack, and hookers" :)

Comment: can you let me know which version of Qt you are using?

Comment: Sure - latest 5.9.1

Comment: @dtech regarding your last edit: I think you are stuck to `item0`, which you can't push again, since you have not removed it from the stack. `pop()` will leave the `initialItem` (the lowest from the stack) on the stack. To remove it, you need to call `clear()`

Comment: `pop()` should remove the top item, that is the last item pushed, which is `item0`.

Comment: OK, evidently you cannot pop the last item to make the stack empty, still doesn't make sense, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

Create them with no parent:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600



    StackView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: sv
        initialItem: Button {
            id: b
            onClicked: sv.push(b1)
            text: "0"
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: b1
        parent: null
        onClicked: sv.push(b2)
        text: "1"
        x: 100
        onParentChanged: console.log('parent', parent, 1)
        onVisibleChanged: console.log('visible', visible, 1)
    }

    Button {
        id: b2
        parent: null
        onClicked: sv.push(b3)
        text: "2"
        x: 200
        onParentChanged: console.log('parent', parent, 2)
        onVisibleChanged: console.log('visible', visible, 2)
    }

    Button {
        id: b3
        parent: null
        onClicked: sv.pop()
        text: "3"
        x: 300
        onParentChanged: console.log('parent', parent, 3)
        onVisibleChanged: console.log('visible', visible, 3)
    }


    Button {
        id: back
        onClicked: sv.pop()
        text: 'pop'
        Binding {
            target: back.background
            property: 'color'
            value: 'orange'
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: clear
        x: 150
        onClicked: sv.clear()
        text: 'clear'
        Binding {
            target: clear.background
            property: 'color'
            value: 'orange'
        }
    }
}
```

In `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` the will be reparented to `null` when you `pop()` them, effectively hiding them.

In `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` they will be reparented to some `ContentItem` but their `visible` property will be set to `false`, hiding them aswell.

To test it, just change line 2 to `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`

**Remember:** `pop()` will leave the item with index `0` on the stack. To remove that, call `clear()`

Comment: Even so, popping doesn't hide the item again.

Comment: If you use `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` they will be reparented to `null` uppon `pop()`. When you use `QtQuick.Controls 1.4` they will be reparented to some `ContentItem` somewhere but the `visible`-property will be set to `false` instead. So no problem here either.

Comment: It remains visible after popping, thus presumably the parent is not null. Using controls 2

Comment: Can you show me an example where I could see them? The `visible`-property is irelevant. My output tells me, the parent is `null` after pop.

Comment: Maybe you talk about the bottom item, that can't be `pop()`ed?